# Display corresponding menu

Tags: routes, nodes, navigation

I've several content types configured to add links in several menus other than the main one and navigation, and I'd like Drupal to show in a left sidebar the corresponding menu it belongs and its siblings and children.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Using blocks!

Create your new menu,  and assign it to your left sidebar block.   then, configure that menu's block settings to only appear on certain content types.

Comment: the thing is, a same content type could belong to different menus, it's a good option if I had a menu per content type.